# Rails.cache.exists?(key) is returning false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-6, heroku-redis

I have deployed Rails Application on heroku
I am using Heroku-redis premium0 addon.

I am checking if key exist in redis then fetch data from redis else call an API,
But sometimes Rails.cache.exist?(key) is returning false even when the key exist in the redis,
For Example
In production.rb

```
 config.cache_store  = :redis_cache_store
```

```
key = "Location_testing123"
if Rails.cache.exists?(key)
   data = Rails.cache.fetch(key)
else
  Rails.logger.info "KEY_NOT_FOUND #{@key},Existing keys are #{Rails.cache.redis.keys}"
  data = call_api
end
```

But I checked my Heroku logs is showing

```
2020-07-23T09:30:31.651892+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-07-23T09:30:31.651740 #10]  INFO -- : [bb090357-d9a3-407b-9f76-efbfb1dd1fde] KEY_NOT_FOUND Location_testing123,Existing keys are ["Location_testing120","Location_testing123","Location_testing124", "stat:processed:2020-07-18"]
```

The above issue is inconsistent, it is happening only sometimes

Comment: Are you setting any kind of TTL on the redis keys?

Comment: @jebentier , Yes but I have mentioned in production.rb
config.cache_store  = :redis_cache_store, { url: ENV['REDIS_URL'] ,expires_in: 24.hours}

Comment: @jebentier , you can also see my log, that key is present in the array as I am printing
Rails.cache.redis.keys

Comment: I have a hunch that the `.keys` method is not filtering out expired keys. The way redis operates with TTL is that it does loose filtering on reading of an object. Redis GC doesn’t actually delete the entry until it’s been expired and untouched for some time. Can you pull the expiration time for the key in question and see if it is in fact expired?

Comment: How do you put data to cache?

Comment: @Yakov I am putting data using this command  Rails.cache.write(key,data)

Comment: Btw, when I call `Rails.cache.exists?` I get `undefined method exists?' for #<ActiveSupport::Cache::RedisCacheStore`. There is `Rails.cache.exist?` without `s` at the end of the method name. Why you don't get the same error? Is there some custom implementation?

Comment: @Yakov sorry that was a typo mistake , its Rails.cache.exist? only

Comment: @jebentier, may be I will check, just to confirm
Rails.cache.redis.ttl(key) is the correct command right??

Comment: Also, you don't need to check if a key exists, `Rails.cache.fetch` can do all the job https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/Store.html#method-i-fetch

Comment: @Yakov I tried Rails.cache.fetch(key) also , it was returning nil

Comment: I mean `Rails.cache.fetch(key) { call_api }`. Please try to call it twice. The second try should take data from the cache.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218427/discussion-between-puja-garg-and-yakov).

Comment: @jebentier i checked the TTL for that key, it was 79336 sec

Comment: Does `key` hold the same value as `@key`?

Comment: @nullTerminator yes both are same